# Paging in jpa, hibernate when select from multiple table

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have 2 class entity have some same properties. How do i select paging from 2 table and cast to a class dto?

```
@Entity
class A {
  var id: Long,
  var name: String,
  var price: Float,
  ...//more
}

class B {
  var id: Long,
  var name: String,
  var price: Float,
  var isSpecial: Boolean,
  ...//more
}
```

I expect select get all from `class A` and `class B` with `isSpecial = true`.
I try with HQL for SELECT NEW but hibernate not support UNION. I try with native query then raise ResultSet exception.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not yet support UNION. You can either use native queries or use [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which works on top of Hibernate and has support for set operations like UNION.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to map the classes [using inheritance](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) and query a common base class. Querying into DTO is possible using [DTO projection](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) then.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a database view using `UNION`. Then [map an entity by the view](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-view-hibernate/) and use it like other entities.